# How do I allow users to click on iOS maps to show a callout in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to build an application where I need to show a callout with details regarding business (name, address etc) when user clicks on the points of interests on the map.

I am able to show callout when there is an annotation. But I want to have a functionality similar to apple maps application, where even without an annotation, users are able to directly tap on the point of interest to show the details about that point of interest.

I have already set the following properties on my mapView:

```
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = true
mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `MKMapViewDelegate` and override Mouse Event

```
override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let eventLocation: NSPoint = theEvent.locationInWindow
    // do something
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)

}
```